# Blender Texture Paint a Voxel Model - 64px x 64px texture - Need Pencil/Voxel Brush

Tags: texture-painting

I am trying to texture paint my voxel model (9k triangles). I managed to unwrap it and to create the texture.

The thing is I need solid colors and I need a voxel/pixel brush, also if I paint over a color the color becomes brighter which is weird. It has to overwrite the color.

Is there somewhere such an option for my needs?
- pencil
- Overwrite colors

I really struggle right now. Probably there is even a better workflow.

[image]

Comment: You could also look at using vertex paint which would allow you to paint the colors as you touch the mesh tvertex, and then maybe you could bake the colors to the uv image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below your color picker there is a Box named Blend and its set to add which is exactly what you said: It will make your color brighter every time. Set it to Normal or Mix (Im not home right now so I can't lookup)

Comment: Thank you very much, it was mix. This already helps me a lot.